# SDL Program not opening on Xming

Tags: ubuntu, xming, sdl

I'm running the Ubuntu app on my windows 10 computer and I'm having trouble getting a SDL program to display with Xming.

Here is the error I get:

```
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display ":0".
```

and here is the sdl code:

```
    /*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2019)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <stdio.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {

    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Xming is able to work with OpenGL programs just fine so I'm not sure on what I need to do in order to fix this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with SDL app, when I tried to run it from WSL-1 (Ubuntu on Windows). I tested several X servers and the only one that worked was VcXsrv that comes with [SmarTTY](https://sysprogs.com/SmarTTY/) and has version 1.19.3.4. Interestingly enough, standalone [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) that has version 1.20.8.1 doesn't work as well as XMing.

So the setup is the following:

1. Download [SmarTTY portable](https://sysprogs.com/SmarTTY/portable/)
2. Go to \SmarttyPortable\VcXsrv and run vcxsrv.exe (don't run xlaunch.exe)
3. In Ubuntu run (not sure that every command is needed)

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
   sudo service dbus start
   ./your-app
   ```

P.S. The app that I try to run is Cataclysm DDA game that uses SDL. I can't run it directly on Windows because somehow Digital Guardian (DGAgent.exe) blocks it so game crashes in seconds after start. So I had to run in WSL Ubuntu with above solution.